# Distance spectra of uniform tilings

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, tiling

Let a uniform tiling be defined by a [vertex configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_configuration) $(n_1.n_2.\cdots.n_k)^m$, which is either spherical, Euclidean or hyperbolic. Assume that the tiling is vertex-transitive, especially that each vertex has the same number of vertices at all distances $d=1,2,3,\dots$ (not the geometrical distance but the number of edges between two vertices).

Let the **distance spectrum** $\delta$ of such a tiling be the vector with $\delta_d$ = number of vertices at distance $d$ (which is by assumption the same for all vertices).

For the spherical uniform tilings, i.e. the [Platonic polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid), the distance spectrum is finite:

- tetrahedron $(3)^3 \rightarrow$ $\delta = \langle 3 \rangle$
- cube $(4)^3 \rightarrow \delta = \langle 3,3,1 \rangle$
- octahedron $(3)^4 \rightarrow \delta = \langle 4,1 \rangle$
- dodecahedron $(5)^3 \rightarrow \delta = \langle 3,6,6,3,1 \rangle$
- icosahedron $(3)^5 \rightarrow \delta = \langle 5,5,1 \rangle$

I am more interested in [uniform tilings of the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tiling) (Euclidean or hyperbolic), which of course have infinite distance spectra which have to be expressed by a function $\delta(d)$.

For the three [regular tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons#Regular_tilings) of the Euclidean plane this function can be given easily:

- triangular $(3)^6 \rightarrow \delta(d) = 6\cdot d$
- square $(4)^4 \rightarrow \delta(d) = 4\cdot d$
- hexagonal $(6)^3 \rightarrow \delta(d) = 3\cdot d$

which seems to depend on $k$ and $m$ in $(n_1.n_2.\cdots.n_k)^m$, but not on the specific value of $n_1$. The general pattern is $\delta(d) = k\cdot m \cdot d$.

But what about arbitrary vertex configurations?

> For which (especially hyperbolic) vertex configurations is $\delta(k)$ known in explicit form – or is
> there even a chance to derive it systematically from $(n_1.n_2.\cdots.n_k)^m$?

I especially wonder if generating functions may be of help.

For my favorite configuration $(3.4)^3$ a manual count gives $\delta(2) = 21$, but it's hard to determine even $\delta(3)$, even with this picture at hand:

[image]

At least some kind of pattern looms: $\delta(2) = 21 = \color{red}{\mathbf{3}} + \color{green}{\mathbf{6}} \cdot \color{blue}{\mathbf{3}}$ which is

- $\color{red}{\mathbf{3}} = m \cdot \min(n_2 - 3, 2)$, i.e. the number of quadrilaterals $m = 3$ times $1$ (would be $2$ if $n_2 - 3 > 1$).
  <sub>$2$ and $3$ are fixed numbers and don't depend on the vertex configuration.</sub>
- $\color{green}{\mathbf{6}} = m \cdot k$ which is the degree of the vertices
- $\color{blue}{\mathbf{3}} = m\cdot k - 3$ 
  <sub>$3$ is a fixed number and doesn't depend on the vertex configuration.</sub>

To sum it up (adding the term $\min(n_1 - 3, 2) = 0$):

$$\delta(2) = m \big(m  k^2 - 3 k + \min(n_1 - 3, 2) + \min(n_2 - 3, 2) \big)$$

In general – i.e. for arbitrary configurations $(n_1.n_2.\cdots.n_k)^m$ with $k>1$ – it should hold that

$$\delta(2) = m \big(m  k^2 - 3 k + \sum_{i=1}^k \min(n_i - 3, 2)\big)$$

Among the non-hyperbolic tilings above, the formula holds for all but

- $(3)^5$ where it yields $10$ instead of $5$
- $(3)^6$ where it yields $18$ instead of $12$
- $(6)^3$ where it yields $15$ instead of $6$

How does the formula for $\delta(2)$ have to be adjusted to cover also these cases?

Comment: A related paper (but mostly about more than two dimensions) is https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9706122.pdf.

Comment: @RichardStanley: Thanks for the hint. The paper is mainly concerned with "graphs based upon the root systems" - whatever that means.

Comment: My understanding is that in the case of, say, cayley graphs of hyperbolic groups (so tilings by octagons etc.), there's no hope to obtain a closed formula. It seems to be a research area,  see e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s006050200043